# NHibernate.MappingException Could not determine type for: Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

i have a asp.net aplication and add a library with my domains objects and xml files.

the trace is:

```
Message=Could not determine type for: VaLibrary.Core.Domain.VAEmpresa, VaLibrary,    Version=1.0.5.18335, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns:    NHibernate.Mapping.Column(IdDev)
```

Source=NHibernate

i search in the web same error, but, solutions are for other mapping options (fluent, castle, etc.) not for xml

my Code class is here

```
using System;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   namespace VaLibrary.Core.Domain {

    public class VAEmpresa {
        private int? _id;
        private string _nombre;
        private string _tipo;
        public VAEmpresa() {
            VAJu_Dev = new List<VAJu>();
            VAJu_Pub = new List<VAJu>();
        }
        public virtual int Id {
            get {
                return (int)this._id;
            }
            set {
                this._id = value;
            }
        }
        public virtual string Nombre {
            get {
                return this._nombre;
            }
            set {
                this._nombre = value;
            }
        }
        public virtual string Tipo {
            get {
                return this._tipo;
            }
            set {
                this._tipo = value;
            }
        }
        public virtual IList<VAJu> VAJu_Dev { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<VAJu> VAJu_Pub { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and reference is:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace VaLibrary.Core.Domain {

    public class VAJu {
        private int? _id;
        private VAEmpresa _idDev;
        private VAEmpresa _idPub;
        private VACon _vACon;
        private string _titulo;
        private int _numerop;
        public VAJu() {
            VApllist = new List<VApllist>();
        }
        public virtual int Id {
            get {
                return (int)this._id;
            }
            set {
                this._id = value;
            }
        }
        public virtual VAEmpresa IdDev {
            get {
                return this._idDev;
            }
            set {
                this._idDev = value;
            }
        }
        public virtual VAEmpresa IdPub {
            get {
                return this._idPub;
            }
            set {
                this._idPub = value;
            }
        }
        public virtual VACon VACon {
            get {
                return this._vACon;
            }
            set {
                this._vACon = value;
            }
        }
        public virtual string Titulo {
            get {
                return this._titulo;
            }
            set {
                this._titulo = value;
            }
        }
        public virtual int Numerop {
            get {
                return this._numerop;
            }
            set {
                this._numerop = value;
            }
        }
        public virtual IList<VApllist> VApllist { get; set; }
    }
}
```

the mappings files are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="VaLibrary" namespace="VaLibrary.Core.Domain" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="VAEmpresa" table="VA-Empresa" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Id" column="Id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Nombre">
      <column name="nombre" sql-type="varchar" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="Tipo">
      <column name="tipo" sql-type="varchar" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <bag name="VAJu_Dev" inverse="true" cascade="none">
      <key column="IdDev" />
      <one-to-many class="VaLibrary.Core.Domain.VAJu, VaLibrary" />
    </bag>
    <bag name="VAJu_Pub" inverse="true" cascade="none">
      <key column="IdPub" />
      <one-to-many class="VaLibrary.Core.Domain.VAJu, VaLibrary" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="VaLibrary" namespace="VaLibrary.Core.Domain" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="VAJu" table="VA-Ju" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Id" column="Id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Titulo">
      <column name="Titulo" sql-type="varchar" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" name="IdDev">
      <column name="IdDev" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="IdDev">
      <column name="IdDev" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" name="IdPub">
      <column name="IdPub" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="IdPub">
      <column name="IdPub" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
    </property>  
    <property name="Numerop">
      <column name="numero-p" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <bag name="VApllist" inverse="true" cascade="none">
      <key column="IdJu" />
      <one-to-many class="VApllist" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

the relantionship in DB is:
Va-Ju.IdDev FK to VA-Empresa.Id PK
Va-JU.IdPub FK to VA-Empresa.Id PK

i try to change  for
 but is the same.

I can do?

thank you very much for your answers

[Edit]

i use Nhibernate 3.2

Comment: Why do you have entity id as nullable. I wonder if that's causing troubles as it doesn't make a lot of sense from data integrity point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping is missing the correct **relational** *(object to object)* mapping. The best way how to explain that, is the example:

Change this:

```
private VAEmpresa _idDev;

public virtual VAEmpresa IdDev 
{
  get { return this._idDev; }
  set { this._idDev = value; }
}
```

Into this:

```
private VAEmpresa _dev;

public virtual VAEmpresa Dev  // Reference Object
{
  get { return this._idDev; }
  set 
  { 
      this._idDev = value; 
      if(_idDev != null)      // assure that with reference change
      {                       // the referenceId is changed as well
          IdDev = _idDev.Id
      }
  }
}
public virtual int IdDev { get; set; } // Refernece Id
```

Now we have two representations of the `Dev` reference *(which is of type `VAEmpresa` and has int id)*. And we can map it working way. So

Change this:

```
<many-to-one insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" name="IdDev">
  <column name="IdDev" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
<property name="IdDev">
  <column name="IdDev" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
</property>
```

Into that:

```
<many-to-one name="Dev" class="VAEmpresa" column="IdDev"
         insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" />
<property name="IdDev" not-null="true" />
```

From that moment, NHibernate will know where to search for `Dev` property in DB. It will be column `IdDev` and class to instantiate is `VAEmpresa`

If the code requires just the *referenceId* `IdDev` ... we also have it.

*SMALL NOTE: my experience is to use different **readonly** setting. The editable is reference, readonly is referencId. That forces the code to work with existing VAEmpresa objects, while IdDev could be any integer. Handling is complicated, but brings fruits later*

Comment: I have had many problems, the code generates me NHG [link](http://nmg.codeplex.com/). do not understand why I had to change many things

Answer (score 0):

The ID may require a type. You have:

```
<id name="Id" column="Id">
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
```

Try specifying a type as follows:

```
<id name="Id" >
  <column name="Id" sql-type="int" not-null="true" unique="true" />
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
```

Another problem is you forgot to put the name of the columns / domains in the bag property. You need to put the actual column name and not the property names. Let me show you for VAJu:

```
 <bag name="VApllist" inverse="true" cascade="none">
  <key column="Id"  />
  <one-to-many class="VaLibrary.Core.Domain.VApllist" column="Id"  />
 </bag>
```

Comment: I fixed the column name property in this solution. Please have a look.

Comment: no working, when i add these, trohw a error "Could not compile the mapping document" in the line of "colum" tag, but i use <id name="Id" column="Id" type="int"> anyway not work :(

Comment: Take "column="Id" out of the "id" tag and add it as follows <column name="Id" sql-type="int" not-null="true" unique="true" />

Comment: I addressed another problem with the way you declare bags. This problem is common throughout the entire piece of code. I appended to the message an example of how to correct this problem.

Comment: thanks for help, but the solution is not going exposed. column is not define, i try <one-to-many class="VApllist"  entity-name="VAJu_Dev"/> but trows Association references unmapped class: VAJu_Dev

Comment: class="VaLibrary.Core.Domain.VApllist"